# Error while using ssh and pbrun with a command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh

I have a command to `ssh` to a sever, `pbrun` to a user and create a directory at a time. Command is executing successfully:

```
ssh severname ' pbrun su - userid - c "mkdir hello" '
```

When I put it in a shell script where the `servername`, `userid` and `directory` names are variable.
Like:

```
ssh $servername ' pbrun su - $userid - c "mkdir $dirname" '
```

I am getting error:

> request reject by pbrun ..

Help me avoid the error.

Note: input value to userid and other variable are correct, I verified them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With single quotes (`'...'`) you're not letting your variables be expanded in the moment you're executing the `ssh` command.
Use double quotes (`"..."`) instead, escaping the embedded ones:

```
ssh $servername " pbrun su - $userid - c \"mkdir $dirname\" "
```